# PHP Online file analyzing

Tags: php

I'm looking for some tutorial on how from a webapplication upload a file and while uploading analyzing it.

I mean a user chooses a file from his computer on a web app, the file is excel. After choosing elaborate it the file is analyzed and some stuff is done, once the work is complete the user is redirect to  a webapp with the results.

I need just some hints on where to start investigating.

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "analyzing"?

Comment: I mean for example analyzing any row of the excel file and do some stuff on a database for each row.

Comment: @thejh what do u suggest? I need some examples :-)

Answer (score 1):

PHP won't be able to do much analysis since it is server-side. It cannot communicate with the file until it is entirely uploaded. You may want to look at creating a Java Applet uploader to analyze a user's file before or during the upload. However, this is not to say you cannot analyze the file with PHP **after** the user has uploaded the file to the server.

Good luck!
Dennis M.

Comment: you are right sorry! so I mean user experience improving, so I want that all look like as a unique process uploading then open the file and analyze it!
Any example?

Comment: If you want to use PHP to analyze the file still, the user will have to stay on the page and, if it's a large file, it will look as though the upload is taking a long time (so I would warn the user ahead of time). If you plan on taking the java route, I would look into JUpload (http://jupload.sourceforge.net/applet-basic.html) as a starting point and if you want to make your own uploader, you can use the code as a basis of understanding how the process would work in Java. I can add a short example to my response; what are you trying to analyze?

Comment: the other option is to trigger a background process to analyze the file once its uploaded, and send a response to the browser saying that the file is being analyzed, rather than process the whole file before sending a response... the user can be given a holding page that polls periodically to see if the analysis has been completed, or a link that they can go back to periodically to see if the analysis is complete

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries available for accessing the data in an Excel workbook, including my own [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) which can read both .xls and .xlsx files. exactly how to transfer data from the workbook to a database depends on the content of the workbook, but basically you need to iterate through each row of a worksheet and determine its cell content, then build a SQL statement to insert that cell content into your database.

You definitely need the file to be uploaded in its entirety before you try reading it though.

Comment: My problem is not analyzing excel file, I know per very well so this kind of work is easy enough, however I don't have web app experience. I would like to have a user experience with some ajax that tell to the user once the upload button is pushed where is the computation of the task. For this I was looking for some examples, of uploading and elaborate file, even a text elaboration is enough to understand.

Comment: @Kerby82 - see my response to RageD's answer